# Can we write stored procedures in IBM graph or JanusGraph? Are they ACID compliant?

Tags: stored-procedures, acid, ibm-graph, janusgraph

I know the basics of how IBM graph and JanusGraph works. Can we write stored procedures for these? Also, are they ACID compliant?

Answer (score 1):

The way you interact with IBM Graph is through separate gremlin script submissions sent over HTTPS, each of which share no state-- so no, you cannot use something like a stored procedure.

Titan/JanusGraph is a stateless JVM interacting with a storage backend; IBM Graph uses Cassandra to store your data, so when we speak of ACID compliance, we are mostly speaking about whether or not Cassandra is ACID compliant. I will leave the answer to that as an exercise to you with a single place to start: https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ArchitectureOverview as (1) there should be plenty of information on this online as Cassandra is super popular and (2) ACID "compliance" is something that means different things to many people.

If you build SystemA on top of DB1 and DB1 is not ACID compliant, that does not mean that SystemA is not ACID compliant. Having said that, Titan/JG does indeed have a notion of transactions which are Durable, but not Consistent, Isolated, or Atomic.